# Add View Context Menu in VS 2015 is Painfully Slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my Visual Studio 2015 MVC project, when I right-click a menu under the Views folder
and select Add -> View... the dialog is painfully slow to appear (about 60 seconds slow).

Some contextual information that might be helpful:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
- Running on a Parallels VM w/8GB (so it probably shouldn't be this slow)
- The project I'm working in has been upgraded from MVC 3 -> 4 -> 5.
- ReSharper 10.0.1

Comment: Been like that since ages, used it on many pc's, laptops still behaves like that. I got already used to it....Microsoft

Comment: My situation is : it becomes slower when project grows larger. Of course, it is fast in new project.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall my operate system, the problem seems resolved. But it came again when my project rewrite the router in MVC5. So I guess the problem is in MVC Router.

If you build a new project, the problem will resolve. So check you MVC project, Especially if you have override your Router in MVC5.